# how do i add two char[] to an List<Object>?

Tags: java, android

so i cant add a random index to pass from i *i[x] = pass[rand.nextInt(pass.size())];*

```
char[] azL = {'a', 'b', 'c'};

char[] nzL = {'0', '1', '2'};


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    initializeValues();
    cha();

    but.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        int Plength = 6;

        char[] i = new char[Plength];

        List<Object> pass = new ArrayList<>();


        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            for (int x = 0; x < Plength; x++) {
                i[x] = pass[rand.nextInt(pass.size())];

            }
            textV.setText(String.valueOf(i));
        }
    });

}
public void cha() {
    List<Object> pass = new ArrayList<>();
    pass.add(azL[rand.nextInt(azL.length)]);
    pass.add(nzL[rand.nextInt(azL.length)]);
}
```

it says "Array type expected; found: 'java.util.List" and I don't know what to do..please help

Answer (score 2):

```
i[x] = pass[rand.nextInt(pass.size())];
```

`pass` is not an array it is A `List`. The syntax you using `[]` is for array.

Correct way of doing it is

```
i[x]  = pass.get(rand.nextInt(pass.size()))
```

Answer (score 1):

this should

```
i[x] = pass[rand.nextInt(pass.size())];
```

be like

```
i[x] =pass.get(rand.nextInt(pass.size()));
```